# Algorithm to move the content of a vector efficiently

Tags: java, algorithm, vector

I have a vector of dimension 3 which will be constantly changing value, e.g., if I remove the content of the position 0 I want to move the remaining cells content the remaining cells to start now from 0.

I currently do it this way (java code) but I feel it is very inefficient.

```
aux = posy[1];
posy[0] = aux;
aux = posy[2];
posy[1] = aux;
posy[2] = 0;
```

Is there another, more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I mean, this is how it is done. Its always going to take O(n) time. Best you can do is use a loop.

Comment: Just store pointers to a head and tail and you won't need to rotate anything.

Comment: For just three elements a loop may be slightly less efficient, I doubt you’ll notice. For many elements you should consider the `ArrayDeque` class, but as I understand this is not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need any auxiliary variable.

```
posy[0] = posy[1];
posy[1] = posy[2];
posy[2] = 0;
```

For moving the opposite way you will need to do it in the opposite order.

No other improvement is possible.

Had you had many elements (say, five elements), I would have recommended you look into the `ArrayDeque` class. It allows insertion and deletion in both ends without shifting the elements. It’s probably implemented with an index pointing to each end as @Jacob G. in a comment suggested doing. For just three elements you could consider it overkill.